# puppet adding timestamp in file content

Tags: puppet

super new to puppet. Could not find good example of how to add timestamp in a file `puppet.pp`

```
node '123' {
  file { '/tmp/hello':
    content => "hello world",
  }

  file { '/tmp/timestamped':
    content => 'date',
  }
```

Just wanted to print current date when this manifest is applied into the file **timestamped**

version is: 4.10

Answer (score 9):

## Puppet (any version)

If you are using version [older than 4.8.0](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-6865) you can use [function `strftime` from the `stdlib` module](http://www.puppetmodule.info/github/simp/puppetlabs-stdlib/puppet_functions_ruby3x/strftime).

## Puppet (version ≥ 4.8.0)

If you are using newer version of Puppet you should use [`Timestamp.new().strftime()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#strftime).

Example (you only need to use one of the assignments):

```ruby
# ISO 8601
$timestamp = Timestamp.new().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z')
notice ($timestamp)

# RFC 822, 1036, 1124, 2822
$timestamp = Timestamp.new().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
notice ($timestamp)

file {'/tmp/timestamped':
   ensure  => file,
   content => "${timestamp}",
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work. Use generate to create and assign to a variable. Then assign the variable to be the file's content.

```
$timestamp = generate('/bin/date', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

file {'/tmp/timestamped':
   content => "$timestamp"
}
```

Comment: Answer is great, but please change the date order to be ISO 8601 compliant! Someone might just copy paste this and then be in for a world of sorting troubles down the line.

Comment: cheers @AndyFoster - compliance adopted